# Beamer - controlling the size of custom bullets

Tags: beamer

I changed the default bullet style in a beamer presentation, but the size of the second-level bullet seems to be larger than the one for the first-level (while I was expecting it to be smaller, or the same size at least). In particular, I'm using `circle` for the first level and `triangle` for the second and third level. Although the size of the third-level triangle seems right, the second-level triangle seems bigger than the first-level circle. Any ideas about how to fix this?

Here is an example:

[image]

And here the code:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Changing bullet and number style. Default options in 
% brackets. Can specify anything different from defaults in braces
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]            % First level item
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]       % Second level item
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]    % Third level item
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title 1}
\begin{itemize}
  \item{Level 1 bullet}
  \item{Level 1 bullet}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{Level 2 bullet}
    \item{Level 2 bullet}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{Level 3 bullet}
      \item{Level 3 bullet}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `\scalebox{}{}` command to adjust the size of the bullet item

In the following code I increased its size, you may however adjust it to values smaller 1 to get a decrease.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Changing bullet and number style. Default options in 
% brackets. Can specify anything different from defaults in braces
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]            % First level item
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]       % Second level item
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\raisebox{0.2em}{\scalebox{1}{$\blacktriangleright$}}}   % Third level item
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title 1}
\begin{itemize}
  \item{Level 1 bullet}
  \item{Level 1 bullet}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{Level 2 bullet}
    \item{Level 2 bullet}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item{Level 3 bullet}
      \item{Level 3 bullet}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image: beamer]

Comment: Two questions I have after using your code. (1) When using `scalebox` to reduce the size of a bullet, the bullet is no longer vertically centered. How to re-center these bullets? (2) If I just add the line `\usepackage[]{mathabx}` to the preamble of my original code, the size of the triangles adjusts automatically, as the picture you attached shows for the level 2 bullets. Why is this happening?

Comment: Regarding 2): I just took one font from the `symbols-a4.pdf` which included the black triangle. I just tried, it works without this package as well. Regarding 1) I am not sure what Beamer does internally with the vertical spacing. I have amended my code accordingly using `\raisebox`